# Equal width on both side of list elements

Tags: html, css

I am designing a menu, which width is 980px. I wanted to style them in such a way that all the li's have same padding from left and right. Means after divisions of all the menu have equal paddings. Example attached.

[image]

Used html and styles are

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Furniture</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Art</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Test</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Testing Cate</span>

        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Testing Category</span>

        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Used Style: -

```css
ul li{
    float: left;
    height: 24px;
    border-right: 1px solid #2e2f2f;
    border-left: 1px solid #595a5b;
}
ul li a {
    padding: 0 27px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 23px;
}
```

Any suggestion how to achieve this.

Comment: whats problem with your css http://jsfiddle.net/dolours/acxBz/

Comment: What is the problem? It works fine...

Comment: Ya correct, but my problem is its not working perfectly fine with all the browsers. Working fine in chrome but rendering for other browsers is not proper. There are not equal padding for others.

Comment: It's working fine in Firefox. Just stating "other browsers" without specifying which browser + version will not help.

Comment: You had to say that coz I was checking in Chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: @PraveenKumar My bad sorry

Answer (score 1):

This will give all `li a` same `padding` of `27px` on both sides and allow them to expand to fill parent `ul`:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 978px; /* 980px - side borders width  --> total width 980px*/
    border-right: 1px solid #2e2f2f;
    border-left: 1px solid #595a5b;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
li {
    line-height: 23px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #2e2f2f;
    border-left: 1px solid #595a5b;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 27px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/vwtey/)

Comment: I updated your demo with width of 980px. Please have a look all the menu items does not have equal padding. http://jsfiddle.net/NpYCG/3/

Comment: i deleted my answer (even though it appointed equal padding and fixed width) because this kind of CSS would be optimal (a `container div` with a fixed width, with a `header div` with `width:100%;`) instead of OP's solution (a header with fixed width)

Comment: the only solution for that is to give equal percentage width to `li` items, for example if you have 10 `li` items set width to `10%`, see the updated demo

Comment: close, but the `Item 4sdssss` does not have equal padding unfortunately (chrome 26.0.1410.43)

Comment: you can't have same width and same padding at the same time because the text width is different in each list item

Comment: hmm.. i dont think they said anything about a "same" width, they just same "same" padding. they just want a header of fixed width. anyways, im gonna post up my solution in a sec.. see how it goes =/

Comment: well because of the 980 fixed width there's no possible way you can have same padding (distance between text and borders) for all list items, what you can do is add `padding: 0 27px` to `li` and `width: auto` this will allow them to have minimum padding of `27px` for larger items but would be bigger in smaller items. see updated demo

Comment: yeah true, though if we assume that there will definitely be 10 labels (NOT as shown in the diagram, some of those are a little small, but if we have 10 roughly equal-size labels), it will be enough to fill 980px and thus have equal padding on both sides(you can see a pic of my soltuion below). i still definitely believe your solution is best for future users looking for a similar solution though.

Answer (score -1):

[fixed header width (980px) + All the li's have same padding from left and right + Matches diagram posted above + cross-browser(chrome+firefox+ie9). enjoy :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGDVt.jpg)

CSS (padding is specified in %):

```
div{
    background:red;
    width:980px;
}
ul{
    display:table;
    list-style:none;
    margin-left:-40px;
    width:100%;
}
ul li{
    background:pink;
    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0% 2% 0% 2%;
    text-align:center;
    width:9%;
}
```

HTML (just added an outer div):

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a title="" href="javascript:void(0);"> <span class="catName">Furniture</span></a>
        </li>
        <!-- and 9 more <li>'s -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

technically, its equal padding.. though of course if you only have 5 small items in a 980px area, they be will unequal. if you just insert exact 10 labels as shown in the diagram, its roughly equal padding (close enough anyways)